Publishing a .NET Framework Project injects .NET Core elements into web.config
My project is .NET Framework 4.8 and the project is SDK style.  The web.config is a basic one that's created for a ASP.NET Web Application (basically MVC).  I created a Publish Profile that publishes to a folder.
When I publish the project, the web.config in the publish folder now has .NET Core entries. Specifically, the process adds the following:
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
</system.webServer>

I was having trouble believing that this is happening (and not a result of something I did), so I replicated it with the following steps:

Create a new ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) - pick MVC in the dialog
Right click on a project and select Upgrade.  Select to upgrade it to SDK style project
Fix up whatever references are missing. Change project type to Library from Console.
Right click on a project, select Publish and create a Folder publish profile.
Publish it.  Compare web.config in the published dir vs the one in the project.  The published one has .NET Core entries.

Why is this happening?  How do I prevent it from happening?  This is not happening if the project is not SDK style.
P.S. Using latest Visual Studio 2022.
P.P.S.  Found the fix.  Add <IsWebConfigTransformDisabled>true</IsWebConfigTransformDisabled> to the first PropertyGroup in the csproj file.

This is happening because your project is using the new SDK-style project format (when u did upgrade), which is common for .NET Core projects but can also be used by .NET Framework projects to take advantage of some of the newer features. When you publish an SDK-style project, the .NET CLI tooling automatically generates a web.config file with the necessary settings to host an ASP.NET Core application on IIS, including the aspNetCore handler and module settings. This is expected behavior for ASP.NET Core projects but can be surprising when seen in a .NET Framework project.
To prevent this from happening, you can:

Manually edit the web.config file after publishing to remove the
ASP.NET Core-specific settings.
Customize the publishing process to avoid generating these settings. This might involve modifying the .csproj file or the publish profile to control the web.config transformation.

You can read more about these here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

An app or library can target a version of .NET Standard. .NET Standard versions represent standardized sets of APIs across all .NET implementations. For example, a library can target .NET Standard 1.6 and gain access to APIs that function across .NET Core and .NET Framework using the same codebase.

Another solution for u is to consider reverting to the old-style project format for .NET Framework project to avoid this issue altogether.

"Customize the publishing process to avoid generating these settings."  That sounds promising.  How do I do that?  I don't see anything specific in the link.

@AngryHacker U can create a custom target in your .csproj file that runs after a certain event in the publishing process. For example, to run a script after all files are gathered for publishing, you might add something like this:
 And now u can overwrite by copy if u want your web.config

Oh, yeah, I am already doing that during the deployment.  Basically what you said, run a powershell script to rip out the .net core changes out of web.config.  I was hoping for a cleaner method like having some entry in the .csproj that would indicate to the build system not to generate  .net core entries in the web.config at all.
Ultimately, I decided to go with your last suggestion - to revert to the old style project format.  The new one just isn't worth the headache for .NET Framework projects.
